# Multiple output Hugging Face

Tags: huggingface-transformers

I want to use pretrained RoBERTa transformer, as an embedding model in two way. Firstly,
i would like to use pooled_output which is outputed from TFAutoModel and also Splade style embedding which can be achieve by using logits outputed in TFAutoModelForMaskedLM.

However I was unable to find a way how I would be able to obtain both of these results.

Answer (score 0):

I have found it is possible to add a parameter to AutoConfig which makes it return all hidden states. This when used on MaskedLM model gives a way to extract the last on which can then be used to extract the vector at [cls] token. This is not an ideal solution because it forces us to return much more data but it atleast is workable.